# pyplot zooming in

Tags: python, matplotlib, zooming

I am trying to plot some data from Flexible Image Transport System (FITS) files, and I wanted to know if anyone knows how to focus on certain regions of a plot's axis. Here is some example code:

```py
import pyfits
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import pylab
from pylab import *
#Assuming I have my data in the current directory
a = pyfits.getdata('fits1.fits')
x = a['data1'] # Let's assume data1 is the column: [0, 1, 1.3, 1.5, 2, 4,  8]
y = a['data2'] # And data2 is the column:          [0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5,3]
plt.plot(x,y)
```

How could I only plot the region from `[1.3 to 4]` in the x-axis?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use the `plt.axis()` function with your limits.

```
plt.axis([x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max])
```

where `x_min`, `x_max`, `y_min`, and `y_max` are the coordinate limits for both axes.

Comment: @nye17 Using `xlim` / `ylim` or `axis` doesnt matter, since `axis` calls `xlim` / `ylim` to perform the operation. Visit the definition of `axis` in the [source code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes.py). `axis` is just a little more convenient since you can manipulate all four limits with one command.

Comment: @MaxPowers You are right, I somehow mistook it as `add_axis`, my bad!

Answer (score 27):

This question has nothing to do with how you manipulate `pyfits`, but simply a matter of adding

```
plt.xlim(1.3, 4.0)
```

to your code before `plt.show()`