# How to create a plot on a interval of x values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create a plot in [matplotlib](/questions/tagged/matplotlib); the original range of `x` values is [0-70], but I wish to zoom in on the interval range of [30-40]. Essentially magnify that range in a separate plot.

Comment: Do you need two subplots or a single plot with a zoomed inset?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pyplot zooming in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400579/pyplot-zooming-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do two separate plots, like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[10,20,30,40,50,60,70] #for example
y=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
ax[0].plot(x,y) # original plot
ax[1].plot(x,y) # second plot
ax[1].set_xlim(30,40) # set a limit on x-axis, is like a zoom
plt.show()
```

And you get

[image]

Comment: Please try running your code and see if it works. Fix the typos. `pet`. It should be 
 `set_xlim`

Comment: thank you, I'm sorry but I clicked on the answer button too fast.

Comment: set_xlim(30,40)  this is the key .. .thank you . i coldnt find it in the tutorials .

Comment: @MosesS: Care to share the tutorials you couldn't find it in?

Comment: chill out Bazingaa .

Answer (score 2):

Besides the other answer, you might also be interested in knowing how to use insets in the figure to highlight some particular range of curve. Here, the first two values in `plt.axes([.2, .5, .3, .3])` define the starting point of your inset figure axis in relative coordinates (0 to 1) and the following two values (.3, .3) defines the x-length and y-length of your inset again. This can be controlled to place the inset at position of interest.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))

x = range(70)
plt.plot(x,x)

ax2 = plt.axes([.2, .5, .3, .3])
ax2.plot(x,x)
ax2.set_xlim(30, 40)
ax2.set_title('Zoomed')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Matplotlib has ways of creating insets. No need to place an axes manually in figure coordinates.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458580/embedding-small-plots-inside-subplots-in-matplotlib) and [this](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/axes_demo.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001088/how-to-add-different-graphs-as-an-inset-in-another-python-graph), it seems to be the most used approach where the coordinates have been used manually. I would love to see other better ways to put an inset. Are you referring to [this](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axes_grid1/inset_locator_demo.html)?

Comment: I'm refering to [this](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axes_grid1/inset_locator_demo.html) and [this](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/zoom_inset_axes.html). In terms of SO answers, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34862213/4124317) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53667739/4124317).

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks. So your comment was not about using `[.2, .5, .3, .3]` which is manual work putting coordinates manually, but to using `ax.inset_axes` instead of `plt.axes` because in the second the fourth link you shared, values have been entered manually just like in my answer

Comment: Well, point is `plt.axes()` takes figure coordinates. But an inset should be bound to an axes (*in*set). `ax.inset_axes` takes axes coordinates, so you place the inset relative to the axes, which makes much more sense. Or in fact any other coordinate system you want to specify.

Comment: Alles klar :) :)

Comment: Though let me mention that personally I'm a big fan of [the axis_grid1 solution](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axes_grid1/inset_locator_demo.html) which does not require any coordinates at all.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: I also find this to be the best solution. It is easy to control a single percentage rather than specifying the extents